# "Day" function returning incorrect value

Tags: vba

So I got the following code that basically loops through the first 15 cells of column A and then exits when it finds a date.

```
 For i = 1 To 15
        
        Start_Time_Value = Worksheets(sheet_name).Range("A" & i).Value
        
        Start_Time_Value = CDate(Start_Time_Value)

        'I remove the milliseconds from the date to be able to use the IsDate function
        my_variable = IsDate(Split(Start_Time_Value, ".")(0))
        
        If my_variable = True And Start_Time_Value <> "00:00:00" Then Exit For
        
    Next i
```

Then I've got a piece of code that extracts the day and the month from the cell value that contained a date.

```
        'Obtain day
        Day_StartTime = Day(Start_Time_Value)
        
        'Obtain month
        Month_StartTime = Month(Start_Time_Value)
```

The thing is that currently Start_Time_Value = "14/09/2021 08:25:08.931" and for some reason both Day_StartTime and Month_StartTime are "9" when I should expect Day_StartTime to be "14"

does anybody know why this is happening?

Edit:

After running Debug.Print Start_Time_Value this is what I obtain
14/09/2021 08:25:08.931

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it is "2021"

Comment: `? Day(Cdate("14/09/2021 08:25:08"))` (after stripping off milliseconds) returns `14` in the Immediate Window, so not sure where you're going wrong.

Comment: @BigBen not sure either, when I hover over the "Start_Time_Value" variable I can clearly see that the day is "14" so I don't know where it is getting "9" from.

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print Start_Time_Value` and report back the output in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen I've included that on my question description now.

Comment: Ok, well you can't call `Day` on that because it includes milliseconds. So what are you calling `Day` on?

Comment: ^^^ you should be using: `Day_StartTime = Day(my_variable)` and `Month_StartTime = Month(my_variable)`

Comment: @BigBen I knew I couldn't use a date with milliseconds on "IsDate" but I didn't know that this also applied with the Day and Month functions. I have updated my code now. It works now. If you submit what you said as an answer I can select it as an answer the solved my problem.

Comment: @ScottCraner that wouldn't work because "my_variable" returns True or False but I get it, I have to remove the milliseconds to use the "Day" and "Month" functions

Answer (score 0):

First, chop the milliseconds.

```vb
For i = 1 To 15        
    If IsDate(Split(Worksheets(sheet_name).Range("A" & i).Value, ".")(0)) Then
        my_variable = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next 

If my_variable = True Then
    Start_Time_Value = CDate(Split(Worksheets(sheet_name).Range("A" & i).Value, ".")(0))

    ' Obtain day.
    Day_StartTime = Day(Start_Time_Value)
        
    ' Obtain month.
    Month_StartTime = Month(Start_Time_Value)
End If
```